# 802.1ar secure device identity certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

Does anybody know the difference between regular x509v3 certificates verses secure device identity certificates? I know that for device identity certificates they really limit what you can use for some of the fields (signature algorithm comes to mind along with expiry time), and the subjectName is unique to the device, but what else is different. Say I were to generate a certificate as follows:

```
$ openssl ecparam -out priv_key.pem -name secp384r1 -genkey
$ openssl req -new -key priv_key.pem -x509 -nodes -out cert.pem
```

and then my cert looks like this:

```
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem 
Certificate:
Data:
Version: 3 (0x2)
Serial Number:
    86:d6:c2:8f:d0:66:0f:ba
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
    Issuer: C=AU, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
    Validity
        Not Before: Jul  1 16:15:55 2015 GMT
        Not After : Jul 31 16:15:55 2015 GMT
    Subject: C=AU, ST=Some-State, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
            Public-Key: (384 bit)
            pub: 
                04:d3:05:98:9b:61:1e:91:22:5b:84:92:6f:09:d9:
                ce:5b:cf:28:de:aa:2f:21:89:5f:95:92:48:7a:b9:
                b1:13:84:21:bc:83:31:9c:45:63:c5:65:d6:80:79:
                f8:53:40:55:c0:10:4a:0d:44:fb:a9:2f:de:2f:c7:
                ea:44:d0:3f:88:05:0c:35:06:b8:f6:b9:e6:25:53:
                f2:05:67:76:df:20:55:76:f8:be:8e:e8:9b:45:19:
                e4:dc:9e:cf:62:d8:95
            ASN1 OID: secp384r1
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            26:D0:6D:95:39:B4:08:E9:DD:B1:9C:3F:AD:76:42:61:0C:26:6B:5C
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:26:D0:6D:95:39:B4:08:E9:DD:B1:9C:3F:AD:76:42:61:0C:26:6B:5C

        X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
            CA:TRUE
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA1
     30:65:02:30:09:e6:83:8b:63:f5:e0:00:df:91:92:92:24:b7:
     62:bf:74:95:29:50:9d:12:f0:37:6a:7b:68:d6:13:df:86:8b:
     b9:d9:b8:ed:9a:30:27:fe:21:2c:40:57:f6:29:93:04:02:31:
     00:8a:68:50:23:56:56:8c:62:2d:01:c0:7c:b4:8d:68:11:6b:
     80:96:c2:79:80:32:00:f1:16:d1:d0:5e:23:f3:c8:99:b8:86:
     05:b1:99:20:04:67:6f:74:94:9e:f5:bc:45
```

What else needs to go into this certificate to consider it a secure device identity certificate?

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal answer, except this one: read device documentation. Different vendors have different requirements on certificates. And there is no such term like "regular x509v3" certificate. Generally, they differ in private and public key usages. Read the documentation and you should find information about certificate requirement.

> and then my cert looks like this:

this is CA, not end entity certificate. CA certificate is used to sign other certificates and CRLs.